# Symfony 3.2 - @Assert - Error message in Form at the wrong position

Tags: forms, symfony, assert

I'm working on a project in Symfony 3.2.

In this project I create an Entity and its Form. And to do the validation of the fields I use the Assert component provided by Symfony.

As you will see in the code below, I have 2 fields with exactly the same constraints implemented.

I have an issue regarding the field 'firstName' error message that do not display at the right position in the form. It basically displays at the top of the form while the error message of the other field displays nicely next to the field as it should.

I have no idea why one field would behave differently form the others.

Here is the code in my Entity:

```
<?php

namespace SRC\MyBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Client
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="client")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="SRC\MyBundle\Repository\ClientRepository")
 */
class Client
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="FirstName", type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(min=2,max=255)
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="LastName", type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(min=2,max=255)
     */
    private $lastName;
```

And here is the code in my Form:

```
<?php
namespace SRC\MyBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

use SRC\MyBundle\Entity\Client;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;

class ClientType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('firstname',      TextType::class,        array('label'  => 'client.entity.firstName'))
            ->add('lastName',       TextType::class,        array('label'  => 'client.entity.lastName'))
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'SRC\MyBundle\Entity\Client'
        ));
    }
}
```

And here is how the form is embedded in the view:

```
{% block table_body %}
    {% include "SRCMyBundle:Tools:pageTitle.html.twig" with {'action': 'edit'} %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                {{ form_start(form) }}
                    {{ form_widget(form) }}

                    <div class="formButtonsContainer">
                        <div class="formButtons">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="{{ zoomURL }}">{{ 'button.cancel'|trans }}</a>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">{{ 'button.save'|trans }}</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {{ form_end(form) }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

From the class I use you may guess that I'm using Bootstrap.
I'm customizing the form to make it compatible with Bootstrap (redefining some blocks from 'form_div_layout.html.twig') but the issue remains even when I get back to the standard ugly form.

I tried to force the option 'error_bubbling' at false as I saw in another topic it can be linked but it changed nothing.

I have the feeling that for some reason the form doesn't manage to map the error to the field hence sending it to the form by default but I'm just guessing at this point.

Does anyone has an idea ?

Thanks for your help ! :)

Comment: How do you embed the form? Please share the view part.

Comment: Edited my previous post to add the view

Comment: Have you overwritten any twig template for form ?

Comment: Yes, I thought about that but the problem remains even when not using it. The raw form displays and the error message is still at the top.